# What operators can be considered as combining two elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra

New to abstract algebra and was wondering if a*b can be something like $\ a^b $ or $\ log_ab$. If not please provide an explanation as to why they aren't.

Comment: You can define $a*b$ as the operation you desire, it strongly depends on the context you're working.

Comment: A binary operation on a set $S$ is literally nothing more than a function $\ast : S \times S \to S$. It can be as simple or as convoluted as you like, or as strange or familiar as you want. Whether it satisfies conditions that you'd like (associativity, existence of an identity, etc.) is highly context dependent.

Comment: Oh alright I think I get it. It can be anything but for groups it's generally taken as addition or multiplication so that there is an inverse for every element

Comment: No, for groups it need not be addition or multiplication. Think, for example, of the dihedral groups as symmetry groups, with composition as operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At it's heart, a binary operation on a set $S$ is just **any** function $*:S\times S\rightarrow S$. So, as long as the expressions make sense for the whole domain and the domain is closed under them, a binary operation can be whatever you want. For instance, $a^b$ defines a perfectly good operation on $\mathbb R_{>0}$. It's harder to get logarithms to work as an operation, since you don't want to put negative numbers into logarithms, but sometimes the output of a logarithm is negative.

However, usually in abstract algebra, you want some nice properties to hold of the operation. For instance, a common thing to demand is that $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$, which is called associativity. Exponentiation fails this property since $(x^y)^z$ is not always equal to $x^{(y^z)}$. In fact, exponentiation taken alone is a rather nasty operation, not satisfying really any identities I can think of. This makes it hard to study through abstract algebra, which generally tries to derive interesting results from identities satisfies by the operation.

Answer (score 1):

A *binary operation* on a set $X$ is any function taking two arguments from $X$, with given order,  and assigning an element of $X$ to them, i.e. is a function $X\times X\to X$. 
For a binary operation $*$ we often use the *infix* notation, letting $x*y:=*(x, y) $.

For exponentiation, we can take $X:=\Bbb R^{>0}$ and then $x^y\in X$ for all $x, y\in X$, so that's a binary operation.

However, for the logarithm, it's harder - if possible at all - to find a set $X$ such that $\log$ is an operation, because of the base we must have $a>0,\ a\ne1$, that is, $X\subseteq \Bbb R^{>0}\setminus\{1\} $, but then some values $\log_xy$ might become negative: *outside of $X$*. To ensure $\log_xy>0$ we can restrict $x, y>1$, but then we have to ensure $\log_xy>1$, and so on..